# Position issues after converting a page from html to php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having a issue when converting my .html page into .php when I do so, one of the elements jumps from it's position.

(Note: the following links to the images will not work if you do not delete one of the extra dots before the png extension I'm sorry that I have to do it this way it's just that I'm new here in the site and I still have a low reputation to post pictures, I really need help)

---

This is how I want it to be and how it displays in the .html page

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzfZf.png]

---

But this is how it turns out after converting to .php
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qZAq.png]

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="top-headlines">
                <ul class="th-content">
                    <a href="#"><li><img src="publicidade/002.jpg" /><h1> Getting
                    freelance jobs is very common</h1> amongst designers and programmers. It gives you the 
                    freedom to use your time the way you wish to and also to work on projects that you 
                    like. But, the problem often arises in finding ample freelance jobs to sustain yourself.
                    Not to worry though. Here’s a list of 10 different websites where programmers and designers 
                    can find freelance jobs. So, if you have been looking for such jobs, take a look.</li></a>

                    <a href="#"><li id="top-left"><img src="publicidade/004.jpg" />
                    <h1>Getting freelance jobs is very common</h1> amongst designers
                    and programmers. It gives you the freedom to use your time the way you wish to and 
                    also to work on projects that you like. But, the problem often arises in finding ample
                    freelance jobs to sustain yourself. Not to worry though. </li></a>
                </ul>

        </div>
```

---

```
    .top-headlines h1{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-family: arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: 0.01em;


}
.top-headlines{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 320px;
    max-height: 420px;
    text-align:justify;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.top-headlines a{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:justify;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.5em;


}
.top-headlines a:hover{
    color: #666666;
}
.top-headlines img{
    width: 275px;
    height: 170px;

}

.th-content li{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:315px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-right: 1px #999999 solid;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style:none;


}
.th-content img{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#top-left{
    width:450px;
    clear:right;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Both images are unavailable.

Comment: Delete the extra `.` @James_1x0

Comment: Just look at the source code. PHP generates html so there should be no differences if you do it right. You should also check your html for errors, for example the only allowed child of a `<ul>` is a `<li>` so that could cause problems.

Comment: @jeroen Definitely, but see my answer.

Comment: @James_1x0 Why would that make a difference between a php and an html page?

Comment: @jereon thank you very much, wrapping the <li> around the anchor tags worked great, php just seems to be really strict about this.

Comment: Once more, thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Make .top-headlines have `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these properties:

```
.top-headlines {
    position:relative;
}
.th-content li{
   width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Codepen for illustration. Images don't load but it shows the positioning:
http://codepen.io/jwktje/pen/kFJpy